# reading sql server log files (ldf) with spark

Tags: apache-spark

this is probably far fetched but... can spark - or any advanced "ETL" technology you know  - connect directly to sql server's log file (the .ldf) - and extract its data?
Agenda is to get SQL server's real time operational data without replicating the whole database first (nor selecting directly from it).
Appreciate your thoughts!
Rea

Comment: besides link-cloning, a different solution that allows ongoing access (instead of snapshot access) is to consider using the mssql "replication" feature will allow you to access data in a replicated database at almost real time speed. the replication feature sends data in almost real time from one db to another without much impact to performance on the main system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question, I have never heard of any tech to read an LDF directly, but there are several products on the market that can "link-clone" a database almost instantly by using some internal tricks. Keep in mind that the data is not copied using these tools, but it allows instant access for use cases like yours.

There may be some free ways to do this, especially using cloud functions, or maybe linked-clone functions that Virtual Machines offer, but I only know about paid products at this time like Dell EMC, Redgate's and Windocks.

The easiest to try that are not in the cloud are:
Red Gate SQL Clone with a 14 day free trial:

1. [Red Gate SQL Clone Link](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-clone/?gclid=CjwKCAiA2fjjBRAjEiwAuewS_TV_zshXlkZFv1xJV9tzlxr1ouiOvt4dwO9-TtuhQOTtnZ8b1LTQuxoC2mEQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)
2. Windocks.com (this is free for some cases, but harder to get started with)